# Is there any natural way to cite a newspaper article in BibTex/LaTeX?

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'd like to be able to cite a newspaper article in LaTeX, but Bibtex seems to have no date field (it has year and month, but that doesn't seem sufficient).  Is there any good way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use the [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html) package which allows the date as an optional field on article.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using double curly braces for the Author field i.e., Author={{China Daily}}
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can insert the date in the month field--see [these comments on the "Blog on LaTeX Matters"](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/08/09/how-to-use-a-bibtex-file/#comment-54).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years late to the party... I would recommend changing to biblatex. bibtex does not support AFAIK the month field for articles, so the above mentioned approach (abusing the "month" field) does not work for artiles which is a major drawback. To the contrary, biblatex allows for fine control of all of such subtle settings.

Comment: This was already suggested —  9 years ago!